# Ensuring links have http:// in rich text fields

Tags: links, automation, http

anyone know of a good plugin that looks for inline links where an editor has added the link like: `example.com` not `http://example.com` and corrects them automatically?

If it was matrix/grid compatible that'd help.

Best, Liam

Comment: inline links like  "bla-bla example.com bla-bla..."  or "bla-bla <a href="example.com">link</a> bla-bla..."?

Comment: The second. Not to automatically parse the links/emails (there's a setting channel-wide for that) but simply add the HTTP:// if they add a link without it in a textarea/text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CK Editor, which is the basis for WYGWAM and Wyvern, will do this when links are added with the link button. Also look at VZ URL: [devot-ee.com/add-ons/vz-url-extension](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/vz-url-extension) which will check links for validity when entered.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Wygwam already so for in-textarea posts I'm already safe there. The http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/vz-url-extension is absolutely 100% what I was looking for for specific fields. Perfecto!